# How to load iframe's parent page css and script?

Tags: javascript, html

How to load iframe's parent page css and script?

I want to load the script and css of the index.html file into an iframe.

There is an iframe tag in the index.html file.

index.html

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common/common.css">
  <script src="js/common/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

iframe.html

```
<head>
    ( I want to load the CSS and scripts in the head tag of the index.html file. )
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "inherit" the CSS of the parent by having such code in the iframe:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if (parent) {
        var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var arrStyleSheets = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("style");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrStyleSheets.length; i++)
            oHead.appendChild(arrStyleSheets[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

From Javacript function calling:-

```
<button type="button" onclick="parent.MyFunc();">Click please</button>
```